# Yandex_money_api: illegal_param_ext_auth_success_uri

Tags: python, api, yandex-api

I try to do a payment with api yandex money.
I use

```
instance_id = ExternalPayment.get_instance_id(client_id)['instance_id']
api = ExternalPayment(instance_id)
def wallet_payments(access_token, ym_account, total, api):
    wallet = Wallet(access_token)
    request_options = {
    "pattern_id": "p2p",
    "to": ym_account,
    "amount_due": total,
    "comment": "test payment comment from yandex-money-python",
    "message": "test payment message from yandex-money-python",
    "label": "testPayment",
    "test_payment": True,
    "test_result": "success"
    }

    request_result = api.request(request_options)
    process_payment = api.process({
    "request_id": request_result['request_id'],
    })
    return process_payment['status']
```

`request_result['status']` returns success, but after

```
`process_payment = api.process({
    "request_id": request_result['request_id'],
    })`
```

I get `{'status': 'refused', 'error': 'illegal_param_ext_auth_success_uri'}`.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the yandex documentation:

> illegal_param_ext_auth_success_uri:
>   The ext_auth_success_uri parameter has a missing or invalid value.

So you probably need to define a ext_auth_success_uri parameter which will be a listener url that receive yandex api response in case of success.

And you probably will need this one too which is the same but in case of error:

> illegal_param_ext_auth_fail_uri:
>   The ext_auth_fail_uri parameter has a missing or invalid value.

source: https://tech.yandex.com/money/doc/dg/reference/process-payment-docpage/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was helpful!